# IE8 Javascript doesnt run unless Developer Tools is open?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

For some reason, in IE8, javascript is not running unless I reload the page with Developer Tools open. I close developer tools and reload the page and the javascript stops working. I'm not getting any error reports (not that they'd be any use anyway).

Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Often that's because you left a `console.log` call in your script. This only works when a debugger is present. You should get a JS error on trying to use it unless you have them turned off.

Comment: I usually use:
if (console) { console.log(object); }

Comment: I've never used console.log. And I've not disabled javascript errors. :/

Comment: It's 2012, the answer is still correct. Under Internet Options -> Advanced -> Browsing -> Unchecking "Disable script debugging" gives you console object without dev tools open. So I did this at the beginning of my code: `window.console = window.console || {log: function() {}};`

Comment: Just saved me hours of debugging! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Close Developer Tools, close IE8, re-open, refresh with clear-cache: CTRL-F5
This should do the trick if you don't have any special JavaScript communicating with Developer Tools.

Comment: Nice idea, I've tried uninstalling IE8 and re-installing and the problem remains.