# iecors - jQuery plugin for CORS in IE 8 + 9 doesn't work on page first load

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cors

I have built an application (applause) but it's having trouble (booo) with CORS in IE 8 + 9.

I am using a plugin for jQuery that provides iecors support (https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/edit/master/src/xdr.js).  The script seems to work, when it loads.  However, on entry to the application the script never seems seems to modify $.ajaxTransport.  It doesn't work. If I refresh the page the script works correctly and life is good.  Strangely it always works if IE opens with the developer console open.

The script loads immediately after jQuery and before any of my own scripts.

It sounds like timing but I'm really unsure why I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `console.log()`.  To test the plugin the code is littered with `console.log()`s.  When the developer tools are open `console` is in the window.  If not, it is throwing errors and causing the scripts to fail.

This took hours to figure out.  Thanks to this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701767/874927.